# publish worker role without storage account

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

In Visual studio when publishing a worker role you need to select an storage account.
 In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yqWL.png) image I have already created and selected a storage account, but my application doesn't need it, if I delete the storage account visual studio won't let me publish the worker role unless I create and select a storage account.
Is there a way to publish a worker role without having a storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to publish a worker role without having a storage
>   account?

**No. You would need a storage account to publish a worker role**.

The reason for this is that a worker role deployment needs a storage account where the package file (*.cspkg) will be stored. The deployment process deploys the package file from that storage account. Once the deployment succeeds, you can delete that storage account.

Other than that, (as mentioned by Aravind in his answer) you would need a storage account if you have enabled diagnostics for your worker role as the diagnostics data for that role is stored in a storage account.

Answer (score 0):

In azure cloud services the diagnostics will be stored in a WADlogs table ( table storage) in the storage account used with the cloud service. You can use some storage explorer to browse through the logs.

also it will be useful if you need to use some storage.Linked resources are easier and one does not have to remember which storage account is used in which service etc.

Comment: but do you know how to publish a worker role without having a storage account?

Comment: try disabling diagnostics and removing the storage connection string from config. it may help. I have not really tried it.  again you will pay only for the storage you use and so if you disable diagnostics nothing will be stored. try it out.